# C# how to find an index of phrase in array of single words

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, sorting, for-loop

I have an array of words lets say

```
string[] myWords = { "Arizona", "District", "Court", "is", "located", "at", ".", "District", "court", "closed" };
```

I need to find an index of phrase "Arizona District Court" so the result should be

```
result = [0,1,2]
```

It should ignore the words "District Court" at index [7,8] because its not a phrase it doesn't have Arizona word before District Court, so should be ignored.

What I have tried is this loop

```
foreach (var word in myWords)
        {
            if (myWords.Any(word.ToLowerInvariant().Contains))
            {
                var wordIndex = word;
            }
        }
```

but it return all matches for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this LINQ query using `SequenceEqual`:

```
string[] myWords = { "Arizona", "District", "Court", "is", "located", "at", ".", "District", "court", "closed" };
string phraseToFind = "Arizona District Court";
string[] phrases = phraseToFind.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

int[] firstMatchingSequenceIndexes = Enumerable.Range(0, myWords.Length)
    .Where(index => myWords.Skip(index).Take(phrases.Length).SequenceEqual(phrases))
    .Select(index => Enumerable.Range(index, phrases.Length).ToArray())
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/wq7Bv0

Explanation:

- the query checks each index of the myWords-array
- it takes a sub-sequence of it with Skip(index) and Take(length)
- it compares this part with the phraseToFind-array
- if they are equal the matching indexes are returned as int[]
- change `First()` to `ToArray` if you want all matches or `Count()` if you want the count

Since you have asked, this is how you would get the complete list:

```
int[][] allMatchingSequenceIndexes = Enumerable.Range(0, myWords.Length)
    .Where(index => myWords.Skip(index).Take(phrases.Length).SequenceEqual(phrases))
    .Select(index => Enumerable.Range(index, phrases.Length).ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```

If you want to ignore the case, so it doesn't matter if it's "arizona" or "Arizona", use the right `StringComparer` in `SequenceEqual`. For example:

```
.Where(index => .... .SequenceEqual(phrases, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

Comment: thanks! to be more precise it should also find any other phrase if they occur, so if there will be another "Arizona District Court"  it should gets its index too, if you can help would appreciate

Comment: @AlexFF1: I have just edited my answer to explain how you would do that.

Comment: thanks you very much for explaining! master piece!

Comment: @AlexFF1: edited it to show an `int[][]` version, with `ToList` you'd get a `List<int[]>`.

Comment: @AlexFF1: if you want to ignore the case have a look at the last part i've just added :)

Comment: do you know how can I ignore commas, so its takes "Arizona District Court," where it has comma at the end

Comment: You can use multiple Split characters. Just use a String[] with word delimiters. Add comma and others like semikolon or period. Use the overload that takes StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries